# how to call preventDefault on event when the argument is the element id?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote function that will be called when pressing on button.
The function argument is the button id - but on this button i need to call the method 'preventDefault'

So as far as I know I must change the argument of my function from the button id to be the button himself to use the `button.preventDefault()`

is there other way to call preventDefault ?

```
 OnClickEventOption1(event)
 {
     event.preventDefault()

     // now I can't know which button was pressed
     // need to call button.preventDefault 
 }

 OnClickEventOption2(event)
 {
     // now I can't call the method preventDefault()
     //event.preventDefault()
 }


 redrer(){

     // option 1 
     return <div>
            <button onClick={this.OnClickEventOption1(this)} id={1} key={1} />
            <button onClick={this.OnClickEventOption1(this)} id={2} key={2} />  
        </div>;

// option 2 
return <div>
    <button onClick={this.OnClickEventOption2(this, 1)} id={1} key={1} />
    <button onClick={this.OnClickEventOption2(this, 2)} id={2} key={2} />
</div>;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code for the button and the called function?

Comment: @Chris add code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ES6:

```
handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = e.target.id;
  //do something with id
}
```

//render

```
return 
  <div>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick} id={1} key={1} />
    <button onClick={this.handleClick} id={2} key={2} />  
  </div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind event on button like this  `onClick= {this.clickHandler.bind(this)}`

Then you get event by default.

You can simply use this `event` as

```
clickHandler(e){
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: @Yanshof, Did you have a chance to look at `event` in `console.log(event)` inside your handler.